# Rails - how to get the records by their rank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a City model that holds names of cities and their respective populations. How would I write a method to show cities by a range of ranks?

For example, I'd like to be able to pass in two numbers to the method for the high end of the ranks and one for the low end. Ie, I could pass in get_cities_by_pop(1,10) would get the top 10 cities by population, while get_cities_by_pop(20,35) would get the cities ranked 20-35 by population.

So far I just have:

```
def get_cities_by_pop(high, low)
  cities = City.all.order('population DESC')
end
```

but I am not sure how to write this logic.

Answer (score 3):

You have everything you need on the [ActiveRecord querying guide page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset).

> You can use limit to specify the number of records to be retrieved,
>   and use offset to specify the number of records to skip before
>   starting to return the records. For example
>
> ```
> Client.limit(5)
> ```
>
> will return a maximum of 5 clients and because it specifies no offset
>   it will return the first 5 in the table. The SQL it executes looks
>   like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 5
> ```
>
> Adding offset to that
>
> ```
> Client.limit(5).offset(30)
> ```
>
> will return instead a maximum of 5 clients beginning with the 31st.
>   The SQL looks like:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM clients LIMIT 5 OFFSET 30
> ```

In this case, the end result would look like:

```
Client.order('population DESC').offset(high-1).limit(low)
```

Comment: In this case, the end result would look like: `Client.order('population DESC').offset(high-1).limit(low)`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it'd be something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this as well

```
def get_cities_by_pop(high, low)
  City.where(population >= ? AND population <= ?, low, high).order('population DESC')
end
```